# ExchangeWebService Appointment Response Options

Tags: exchangewebservices

This might be a short lived question.

When creating an Appointment object with Exchange Web Service - is it possible to disable the Repsonse Options: Accept / Decline / Tentative?

Essentially, an appointment needs to be set in the recipient calendar and not be "actionable".

The AllowedResponseActions property is readonly but I was hoping there was a way of setting that property when creating the Appointment.

Not sure if this is possible - I have searched for a while but I could not find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I didn't find any API for your needs. However, I'm not sure if you use the PidTagResponseRequested extended property to disable the Response Options. Please refer to the following code:

```
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
            appointment.Subject = "TestApt";
            appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);

            ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagResponseRequested = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0063, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagResponseRequested, false);
            appointment.Save();
            appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user@domain.com");
            appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged);
```

Reference link: [Create an appointment using C# & EWS and set "Response Options"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Exchange/en-US/663519b9-6930-4500-81d4-aec573993c48/create-an-appointment-using-c-amp-ews-and-set-quotresponse-optionsquot?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Also, [use group policy to disable the tentative response option](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/disable-dont-send-response/)

Comment: Hi Simon - first of all thanks for the research. The PidTagResponseRequested extended property seems to act the same as the Appointment "IsResponseRequested" property.  What I am hoping to achieve (and I'm not sure if possible) is to have the response options "greyed out".